# Android FCM Push Channel Id is always null

Tags: android, firebase-cloud-messaging, notification-channel

I have a custom notification channel that never gets triggered. I read all the documentation for server and client but I'm still missing something.

**What I want**

I want to send a high-priority push notification via FCM to eventually wake up a foreground service in the app. Therefore I defined a custom notification channel. I want to receive the push, find out that it was sent to the custom channel, and show a notification.

**My Problem**

I receive all push notifications from firebase as expected but the channelId is always null.

**The Setup**

We use FCM directly on both sides, the server and the android app.
Our users use Android 8.1 and higher. No legacy push is needed.

The backend sends a JSON that looks like the following:

```
{
    "notification": {
        "android_channel_id": "MY_High_Prio_Push_Channel"
    },
    "data": {
        "notificationBody": "BodyText",
        "notificationTitle": "Title"
    },
    "priority": "high"
}
```

The App has registered the push channel successfully. I can see it in the device settings. The push channel will be re-registered on any app start like this

```
private fun registerHighPrioPushToRestartTheForegroundService() {
    val notificationManager = getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
    val channel = NotificationChannel(getString(R.string.push_channel_id_high_prio), getString(R.string.push_channgel_sync_with_high_prio), NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH)
    channel.setShowBadge(true)
    notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel)
}
```

**At Runtime**

If the android device receives a push from FCM onNewMessageReceived() is called. I then check what channelId it was sent to by calling:

```
if (remoteMessage.notification?.channelId == getString(R.string.push_channel_id_high_prio)) {
    // I would love to do my channel specific stuff here
}
```

As you can see in the screenshot below the body contains the full JSON. All other values are null.

[image]

Comment: It seems the JSON will be delivered in the body tag (see the screenshot). This does not happen if I send a push via FCM Console. I will post a full answer as soon as I found out what exactly is wrong. For now I have to find out what the correct JSON formatting the server needs to send.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was on the server side. The whole JSON for the push was put in the body tag of the notification. Now that this is fixed we send a JSON like the following and the parsing in the client works as expected. We removed the notification tag so that `onMessageReceived()` will be called on every single push.

```
{
    "to": "{devicePushToken}",
    "android": {
        "priority": "high"
    },
    "priority": 10,
    "data": {
        "title": "Some Title",
        "body": "Some Message",
        "android_channel_id": "yourUniquePushId"
    }
}
```